# Pandas data not being plotted

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following simple code to plot specific data sets from this file https://easyupload.io/mdci9u

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url=r'/path_to_file/Book.xlsx'

df1  = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name=0,sep='\s*,\s*', index_col=0)
print(df1) 
x=df1.iloc[:,11].values.tolist()
y=df1.iloc[:,17].values.tolist()
print(x)
fig, axs=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))

axs.plot=(x,y)
```

Whenever I try to run the code, only an empty graph with no data plotted appears. I cannot troubleshoot why my data is not being plotted. Is it something related to my dataframe? When I print `df1` everything seems just fine.

I am using Jupyter Notebook.

Could someone try to help me understand the problem?

All help is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Try `axs.plot(x,y)`

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake in the **last line**. It should be

> axs.plot(x,y)

Instead, you have used an equal sign which is why you got an empty graph.